# what's the meaning "o" in the Hibernate HQL

Tags: hibernate

```
String hql="select o from"+entityClass.getSimpleName()+" o where 1=1";

if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(whereHql)){
hql=hql+whereHql;

}

String orderByStr=this.buildOrderBy(orderBy);

hql=hql+orderByStr;
```

//what's the meaning of "o" in the "select o".

Answer (score 0):

`o` is alias. It means all fields of entityClass.
The query result is list of entityClass instances

Comment: it is a placeholder?

Comment: thank you.i know it now.it means "select * from entityClass"